# JQuery replace select option label based on another field's value

Tags: jquery

I have two select fields - *wpvcountry* and *wpvregion*.

If *wpvcountry* has option 1 selected (ie. with a value of 0), I want to replace the label of *wpvregion*'s option 1 with the text **Please select a country first**

Here's my code so far:

```
if ( $('select[name="wpvcountry"]').val() == 0 ) {

    $('select[name="wpvregion"]').val(0).text('Please select a country first');

}
```

This currently just overwrites all the select options, resulting in this:

```
<select name="wpvregion" class="form-control">Please select a country first</select>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first I will complain you about **how Your code work**

```
$('select[name="wpvregion"]').val(0).text('Please select a country first');
```

> 1. `$('select[name="wpvregion"]')` - Will get the `<select name="wpvregion">` element
> 2. When call `.val(0)` will make `<select>` select to value **0** or mean option will select `<option value="0">` **But not get `<option value="0">` element**
> 3. Call `.text('Please select a country first')` will set new text inside `<select>...</select>` to `<select>Please select a country first</select>` not to `<option>` because element still `<select>`

**BTW** if you need to set `<option value="0">` you need to call

```
$('select[name="wpvregion"]')
    .children('option[value ="0"]') //--> will get option value "0" element 
    .text('Please select a country first');
```

OR

```
$('select[name="wpvregion"] option[value ="0"]') //--> will get option value "0" element 
    .text('Please select a country first');
```

here for demo...

```js
countryCheck();
$('select[name="wpvcountry"]').on('change', function() {
  countryCheck();
});

function countryCheck(){
  if ($('select[name="wpvcountry"]').val() == "0") {
    $('select[name="wpvregion"]').val('0');
    $('select[name="wpvregion"] option[value ="0"]')
      .text('Please select a country first');
    $('select[name="wpvregion"] option').hide();
  } else {
    $('select[name="wpvregion"] option[value ="0"]')
      .text('-');
    $('select[name="wpvregion"] option').show();
    //country = $('select[name="wpvcountry"]').val();
    //getRegion(country);        -->Get country region here
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="wpvcountry">
  <option value="0">-----</option>
  <option value="US">United State</option>
  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="JP">Japan</option>
</select>
<select name="wpvregion">
  <option value="0">-</option>
  <option value="Loading" disabled>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="wpvcountry" class="form-control">
    <option value=0></option>
    <option value=1>A</option>
    <option value=2>B</option>
    <option value=3>C</option>
</select>

<select name="wpvregion" class="form-control"></select>
```

In your script section:

```
var val = $('select[name="wpvcountry"]').val();
if (val == 0) {
   $('select[name="wpvregion"]').html('<option value=0>Please select a country first</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this

```
$('select[name="wpvcountry"]').change(function(){

        if ( $(this).val() == '0' ) {

           $('select[name="wpvregion"]').prepend("<option value='0'>Please select a country first</option>");

        }
});
```